# Bazel error parsing tf.estimator model

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel, tensorflow-estimator

I'm trying to make a *.pb model using `tf.estimator` and `export_savedmodel()`, it is a simple classifier to classify iris dataset (4 features, 3 classes):

```
import tensorflow as tf


num_epoch = 500
num_train = 120
num_test = 30

# 1 Define input function
def input_function(x, y, is_train):
    dict_x = {
        "thisisinput" : x,
    }

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
        dict_x, y
    ))

    if is_train:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(num_train).repeat(num_epoch).batch(num_train)
    else:   
        dataset = dataset.batch(num_test)

    return dataset


def my_serving_input_fn():
    input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.string, [None], name='input_tensors')
    receiver_tensors = {"inputs" : input_data}

    # 2 Define feature columns
    feature_columns = [
        tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="thisisinput", shape=4),]
    features = tf.parse_example(
        input_data, 
        tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_columns))

    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensors)


def main(argv):
    tf.set_random_seed(1103) # avoiding different result of random

    # 2 Define feature columns
    feature_columns = [
        tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="thisisinput", shape=4),]

    # 3 Define an estimator
    classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
        feature_columns=feature_columns,
        hidden_units=[10],
        n_classes=3,
        optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001),
        activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
        model_dir = 'modeliris2/'
    )

    # Train the model
    classifier.train(
        input_fn=lambda:input_function(xtrain, ytrain, True)
    )

    # Evaluate the model
    eval_result = classifier.evaluate(
        input_fn=lambda:input_function(xtest, ytest, False)
    )

    print('\nTest set accuracy: {accuracy:0.3f}\n'.format(**eval_result))
    print('\nSaving models...')
    classifier.export_savedmodel("modeliris2pb", my_serving_input_fn)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
    tf.app.run(main)
```

Which will produce a `saved_model.pb` file. I've confirmed that the model works.  I can also make another program which loads and runs it. Now, I want to summarize and freeze the model using Bazel.  If I build Bazel and then run the following command:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph \
--in_graph=saved_model.pb
```

I get the following error:

> [libprotobuf ERROR external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc:307] Error parsing text-format tensorflow.GraphDef: 1:1: Invalid control characters encountered in text.
>   [libprotobuf ERROR external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc:307] Error parsing text-format tensorflow.GraphDef: 1:4: Interpreting non ascii codepoint 218.
>   [libprotobuf ERROR external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc:307] Error parsing text-format tensorflow.GraphDef: 1:4: Expected identifier, got: �
>   2018-08-14 11:50:17.759617: E tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph_main.cc:320] Loading graph 'saved_model.pb' failed with Can't parse saved_model.pb as binary proto
>      (both text and binary parsing failed for file saved_model.pb)
>   2018-08-14 11:50:17.759670: E tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph_main.cc:322] usage: bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph
>   Flags:
>     --in_graph=""                       string  input graph file name
>     --print_structure=false             bool    whether to print the network connections of the graph

I don't understand this error.  I've tried to use [inception pb file](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/image/imagenet/inception-2015-12-05.tgz) and it works perfectly, so I think the problem is on how `tf.estimator` builds the `.pb` file.

Am I missing something when using `export_savedmodel()` or `tf.estimator` to create a saved model?

**UPDATE**

Tensorflow version: v1.9.0-0-g25c197e023 1.9.0

Result of `tf_env_collect.sh`:

```
== cat /etc/issue ===============================================
Linux rianadam 4.15.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 10 17:58:07 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
VERSION="18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic

== are we in docker =============================================
No

== compiler =====================================================
c++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


== uname -a =====================================================
Linux rianadam 4.15.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 10 17:58:07 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

== check pips ===================================================
numpy               1.15.0 
protobuf            3.6.0  
tensorflow-gpu      1.9.0  

== check for virtualenv =========================================
True

== tensorflow import ============================================
tf.VERSION = 1.9.0
tf.GIT_VERSION = v1.9.0-0-g25c197e023
tf.COMPILER_VERSION = v1.9.0-0-g25c197e023
Sanity check: array([1], dtype=int32)
/home/rian/NgodingYuk/tf_env/env/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
return f(*args, **kwds)
/home/rian/NgodingYuk/tf_env/env/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
return f(*args, **kwds)

== env ==========================================================
LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64:
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is unset

== nvidia-smi ===================================================
Tue Aug 21 11:13:55 2018       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.77                 Driver Version: 390.77                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce 920M        Off  | 00000000:04:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| N/A   51C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    367MiB /  2004MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                    Not Supported                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

== cuda libs  ===================================================
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcudart_static.a
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcudart.so.9.0.176
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/doc/man/man7/libcudart.7
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/doc/man/man7/libcudart.so.7
```

Comment: Have you opened an issue with tensorflow regarding this issue?

Comment: I'm not really sure it's a bug or not, in Tensorflow issue's note it is said to ask here first :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this same problem when I was trying to find the input/output nodes from a model that I had trained using a [custom tf.Estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/custom_estimators).  The error is from the fact that the output that you get when when using `export_savedmodel` is a ***servable*** (which is a, as I understand it currently, a `GraphDef` and other meta data) and not simply just a `GraphDef`.

To find the input and output nodes, you can do.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.saved_model import tag_constants

with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    gf = tf.saved_model.loader.load(
        sess,
        [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
        "/path/to/saved/model/")

    nodes = gf.graph_def.node
    print([n.name + " -> " + n.op for n in nodes
           if n.op in ('Softmax', 'Placeholder')])

    # ... ['Placeholder -> Placeholder',
    #      'dnn/head/predictions/probabilities -> Softmax']
```

I used the canned DNNEstimator as well so the OP's nodes should be the same as mine, other users, your operation names may be different than `Placeholder` and `Softmax` depending on your classifier.

Now that you have the names of your input/output nodes, you can freeze the graph, which is addressed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/README.md)

> If you want to work with the values of your trained parameters, for example to quantize weights, you'll need to run tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py to convert the checkpoint values into embedded constants within the graph file itself.

```
#!/bin/bash

python ./freeze_graph.py \
  --in_graph="/path/to/model/saved_model.pb" \
  --input_checkpoint="/MyModel/model.ckpt-xxxx" \
  --output_graph="/home/user/pruned_saved_model_or_whatever.pb" \
  --input_saved_model_dir="/path/to/model" \
  --output_node_names="dnn/head/predictions/probabilities" \
```

then assuming you have `graph_transforms` built

```
#!/bin/bash

tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph \
  --in_graph=pruned_saved_model_or_whatever.pb
```

**Output**:

```
Found 1 possible inputs: (name=Placeholder, type=string(7), shape=[?])
No variables spotted.
Found 1 possible outputs: (name=dnn/head/predictions/probabilities, op=Softmax)
Found 256974297 (256.97M) const parameters, 0 (0) variable parameters, and 0 
control_edges
Op types used: 155 Const, 41 Identity, 32 RegexReplace, 18 Gather, 9 
StridedSlice, 9 MatMul, 6 Shape, 6 Reshape, 6 Relu, 5 ConcatV2, 4 BiasAdd, 4 
Add, 3 ExpandDims, 3 Pack, 2 NotEqual, 2 Where, 2 Select, 2 StringJoin, 2 Cast, 
2 DynamicPartition, 2 Fill, 2 Maximum, 1 Size, 1 Unique, 1 Tanh, 1 Sum, 1 
StringToHashBucketFast, 1 StringSplit, 1 Equal, 1 Squeeze, 1 Square, 1 
SparseToDense, 1 SparseSegmentSqrtN, 1 SparseFillEmptyRows, 1 Softmax, 1 
FloorDiv, 1 Rsqrt, 1 FloorMod, 1 HashTableV2, 1 LookupTableFindV2, 1 Range, 1 
Prod, 1 Placeholder, 1 ParallelDynamicStitch, 1 LookupTableSizeV2, 1 Max, 1 Mul
To use with tensorflow/tools/benchmark:benchmark_model try these arguments:
bazel run tensorflow/tools/benchmark:benchmark_model -- -- 
graph=pruned_saved_model.pb --show_flops --input_layer=Placeholder -- 
input_layer_type=string --input_layer_shape=-1 -- 
output_layer=dnn/head/predictions/probabilities
```

Hope this helps.

**Update (2018-12-03)**:

A related [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/1078#issuecomment-443906077) I opened that seems to be resolved in a detailed blog post which is listed at the end of the ticket.

Comment: wow, thank you, your code help me to find the input and output node, and also summarize graph works now using your step-by-step :)

Comment: I just realized my pruned_saved_model_or_whatever.pb can't be opened with `tensorflow.contrib.from_saved_model`. The error said `MetaGraphDef associated with tags 'serve' could not be found in SavedModel`, do you know why this happened?

Comment: Once you freeze the graph, it is no longer a `saved model`.